# Singly-linked list queue

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list, queue

I recently learned the core .NET `Queue` type uses arrays internally, and that this is actually much more efficient. I've had a go at writing a singly-linked list version of a queue, `MyQueue`.

Running basic stopwatch times against this type and the .NET type shows about 50ms difference when queuing 1 million items and checking the length.

How can it be improved?

**MyQueueNode**

```
namespace MyQ.Core
{
    public class MyQueueNode<T> : IMyQueueNode<T>
    {
        private MyQueueNode<T> _nextNode;

        private T _value;

        public MyQueueNode(T value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public void SetNextNode(ref MyQueueNode<T> nextNode)
        {
            _nextNode = nextNode;
        }

        public MyQueueNode<T> GetNextNode()
        {
            return _nextNode;
        }

        public T GetValue()
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyQueue**

```
namespace MyQ.Core
{
    public class MyQueue<T> : IMyQueue<T> where T : class
    {
        private volatile MyQueueNode<T> _headNode, _tailNode;

        public void Enqueue(T item)
        {
            MyQueueNode<T> newNode = new MyQueueNode<T>(item);

            if (_headNode == null)
            {
                _headNode = newNode;
                _tailNode = _headNode;
            }
            else
            {
                _tailNode.SetNextNode(ref newNode);
                _tailNode = newNode;
            }

            _length++;
        }

        public T Dequeue()
        {
            if(_headNode == null)
            {
                throw new QueueEmptyException();
            }

            T value = _headNode.GetValue();

            _headNode = _headNode.GetNextNode();

            _length--;

            return value;
        }

        public T Peek()
        {
            if(_headNode == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return _headNode.GetValue();
        }

        private long _length = 0;

        public long Length => _length;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the complete code, I'm just quite anal about organisation and use those comments to separate methods from member fields and to group methods by functionality, like others might use `#region` I've removed them so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use volatile in the below line

```
    private volatile MyQueueNode<T> _headNode, _tailNode;
```

Link https://www.infoworld.com/article/3229360/application-development/how-to-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-c.html

Comment: A short explanation why it is bad to use `volatile` here would be better than just a link.

Comment: Vishnu are you suggesting I should make the `_value` field within the node `volatile` instead of the class that it's contained within? That's what I gather from the article.

Answer (score 1):

MyQueueNode:

- where is `IMyQueueNode<T>`?
- `_value` can be made `readonly`
- there is no need for `MyQueueNode` to be `public`. You should restrict its access modifier as much as possible. Clients don't need to see your queue internals.
- in `SetNextNode` there is no need to pass argument by reference

MyQueue:

- `QueueEmptyException` is not defined.
- `Peek` method returns `null` on empty queue. What if there is `null` as data value? You might consider throwing an exception as seen in `Dequeue` and let user check queue by checking its length before the `Peek` is called.
- instead of:

  ```
  private long _length = 0;
  public long Length => _length;
  ```

  you might consider comfortable using auto property (and changing references to _length):

  ```
  public long Length { get; private set; }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

### Data Corruption

Your class is not thread-safe. Using the *volatile* keyword could cause data corruption because of this. Without this keyword, optimizations might occur that read the field only once in a given scope.

Let's have a look at `Dequeue`. The `_headNode` is read 3 times into memory, since it's volatile. What if `_headNode` is not null the 1st read, but gets nullified by another thread before the 2nd read? Exactly, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` on `_headNode.GetValue();` Remove the volatile keyword and gain performance. Your implementation isn't thread-safe anyway.

> ```
> public T Dequeue()
> {
>     // atomic read of _headNode 
>     if(_headNode == null)
>     {
>         throw new QueueEmptyException();
>     }
>
>     // atomic read of _headNode
>     T value = _headNode.GetValue();
>
>     // atomic read of _headNode
>     _headNode = _headNode.GetNextNode();
>
>     _length--;
>
>     return value;
> }
> ```

### Collection Compliance

You have provided a custom property `Length`. It's better to implement `ICollection<T>` and provide `Count`. This way, your class is way more reusable.